# array value over write

Tags: c, linux, gcc

hello every one i am facing a strange problem i my code i am reading values from the file and file has rows and columns  i am storing the second column in my array

but the problem i that when i first time copy in my position encryption[0] = token

i works well when i store at position encryption [1] my encryption [0] value over write with and become the same as encryption[1] the again at third loop encryption [0] ,encryption [1] become same as encryption [2] so in the end all values become the last sored value

here is my code kingly help me

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{    
    FILE * f1 =  fopen("2.19.18.110_202.142.175.104.csv" , "r");
    if(f1==NULL)
    {
      printf("not open");    
    }
    char ch;
    int row =0;
    int col=0;
    while(ch!=EOF)
    {
        ch = fgetc(f1);
        if(ch=='\n')
            row++;
        if(ch==' ')
            col++;
    }
    fclose(f1);
    int b=0;
    int gg=0;
    //for( b=0;b<row;b++)
    char * encryption[row];
    char  payload[col*10];
    FILE * f2 =  fopen("2.19.18.110_202.142.175.104.csv" , "r");

    while( fgets ( payload, sizeof payload, f2)!=NULL)
    {
        int col1=0;
        printf("b= %d\t" , b);
        //  fgets ( payload, sizeof payload, f2);
        fputs(payload ,stdout);
        printf("\n\n");
        char *token;

        token = strtok(payload, " ");
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");  
        encryption[gg] = token;
        printf("token %s\n" ,token);   
        gg=gg+1;    

        printf("encryption %s\n" ,encryption[0]);    
        printf("encryption %s\n" ,encryption[1]);    
        printf("encryption %s\n" ,encryption[2]);    
        printf("encryption %s\n" ,encryption[3]);


        token = strtok(NULL, " "); 
        while ( token != NULL)
        {
          token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok sir thanks can u please tell me how i mean using malloc......??

Comment: Your code-formatting is very ugly, so ugly my brain refuses to help you; next time look at the preview. Also, why do you keep out-commented code in your sample?

Comment: Your code is pretty much a nice POS. The indentation is more than horrible, the variable names are meaningless...

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I fixed the indendation at least, but because I don't have edit-privileges yet, it awaits community-agreement in some pipeline :/

Comment: Sajid should be given the opportunity to format his own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`encryption[]` is just an array of pointers - for each element you need to `malloc()` sufficient memory (`strlen(token) + 1` bytes) and then use `strcpy()` to copy the string contents from `token` to `encryption[gg]`.

Change:

```
token = strtok(NULL, " ");  
encryption[gg] = token;
```

to:

```
token = strtok(NULL, " ");  
encryption[gg] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
strcpy(encryption[gg], token);
```

Don't forget to `free()` each element of `encryption` later when you're done, otherwise you'll leak memory.

Comment: sir to free memory do i have 2 write free(encryption)?

Comment: @sajid: no, if you `malloc` each element individually then you need to `free` each element individually, e.g. `for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) free(encryption[i]);`